# Chances of Eurostar extending to Germany

Tags: schengen, trains, eu, eurostar

With the recent fusion of Thalys into Eurostar, Eurostar will now also serve routes into Germany. As the travel from the Schengen area to GB requires passport checks all current Eurostar stations are equipped with security checks before access to the station.

If Eurostar were to extend their direct connection to London further than Bruxelles, say Liège, Aachen or Köln, they would somehow need to build further security checks at these stations or perhaps change their operations to conduct passport checks onboard the train or only in London. What are the chances that Eurostar will do so?

Comment: I've changed "EU" to "Schengen area" because travel from Ireland to Britain is also travel from EU to GB.

Comment: @phoog Does travel from Ireland to UK or GB not require a passport?

Comment: @YPOC in general there are no passport checks, but you still need to legally be allowed to enter - presence in one country doesn't automatically give you that right. In addition there are sometimes passport checks imposed on certain methods of entry; I think they consistently check passports when flying from the UK to Dublin Airport, but for instance if you flew to Belfast and then crossed the border by rail you'd have no checks, and equally if you crossed by ferry from Holyhead to Dublin I believe there are also no checks.

Comment: @YPOC not if you are a citizen of the UK or of Ireland (and if challenged on that you can prove your citizenship by any means).

Comment: @Muzer if I understand correctly, any airline that requires passports of UK or Irish citizens flying between the two countries (if there is any such airline) does so as a matter of company policy concerning identification, not as a requirement of immigration law. For example, BA says "if you are a citizen of the UK or Republic of Ireland who was born in that country you do not need a passport to travel between the two countries but you do require some form of photographic identification, such as a driving licence."

Comment: DB tried to start the route back when the UK was an EU member, they never did

Comment: it's not really critical, as you can already buy combined tickets from London to Germany, typically with a simple change in Bruxelles Midi) (i.e. with guaranteed connections)

Comment: @njzk2 I will point out that (unless you know something I don't) the tickets themselves are not combined at the moment (I expect this to change when the Thalys rebranding as Eurostar happens); however as long as your connecting train is high-speed (which most of them are) the connection will be guaranteed by Railteam HOTNAT. In the past you could buy through tickets on the Eurostar from DB, but I believe this to no longer be the case. Any third party selling them just sells you two separate tickets.

Comment: @Muzer I haven't actually booked a ticket myself, but the international DB website shows the booking. Given that it's sold by DB, I would assume that that's a single ticket, but I haven't read the fine prints.

How does hotnat work in the context of buying to separate tickets, though?

Comment: @njzk2 believe you will now receive two separate tickets when buying like that. I could be wrong. In terms of HOTNAT, you just need to get your next ticket endorsed with a special stamp, ideally by staff on the train (who carry those stamps) but if not by station staff. Then if the next train you want to catch has mandatory reservations you also in theory go to a ticket office (I believe eg Brussels has a special one in a convenient location for interchanging passengers) and get a free reservation on the next train - but you will be allowed to use all seats incl. tip-up seats and bar seats.

Comment: @Muzer thanks for the clarification. I hope the train staff is aware of that (and I hope it covers station changes as well (as DB intl I think sells connection with a change of station in, e.g., Paris)

Comment: @njzk2 Railteam HOTNAT only applies to same-station *but* has a special exception for Paris, so you should be covered there. Note that Railteam HOTNAT also only applies to connections between two high-speed trains. If you're connecting between high-speed and conventional trains or two conventional trains you might instead be covered by AJC (Agreement on Journey Continuation) but this one is only between national operators, so no Eurostar or Thalys.

Comment: @YPOC, your recent edit is unlikely to be enough to reopen the question and it makes the existing answer look odd, not answering your question as it now is. After the roll back you can add your new subquestions in an addition at the bottom of the question, not as a change of the whole question.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you for your feedback. My intent was to let the author of the answer know of my edit to give them a chance to edit their answer as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very very low. In terms of its route network to the UK, Eurostar has, since Brexit, been cutting it back rather than expanding it. This is because there is currently simply not enough capacity at St Pancras station for the new border checks, and they are having to leave some of their trains partially empty as there is no way to get all the people through passport control in time. This situation is expected to get worse before it gets better, as EES, the new Entry/Exit System for Schengen (which is to be introduced coinciding with ETIAS), will require collection of fingerprints, which the EU does not currently have on file for UK citizens.

As a result of all this, Eurostar have abandoned the two Kent stations and Calais, along with routes to the South of France, Disneyland, and the Alps. In addition, due to a situation beyond their control they are highly likely to have to temporarily abandon their route to Amsterdam as well. Until this situation at St Pancras can be resolved, the chances of Eurostar expanding its route network are slim.

However, in one very technically correct sense, Eurostar actually are expanding to Germany. This is because they have recently merged with Thalys, a company which runs international high-speed trains within Western Europe. Thalys will soon (from October) be rebranded Eurostar. You can expect to then be able to purchase through tickets from London to Germany, but it will still require a physical change of trains. Given the existence of Railteam (an agreement between high speed rail operators in Western Europe) guaranteeing onward connections with their "HOTNAT" (Hop On The Next Available Train) system in the case of delays by other operators, this through ticketing isn't actually as important as you might first expect. But you can perhaps expect a discount over the current cost of buying two tickets separately.

Comment: "which the EU does not currently have on file for UK citizens": nor for anyone else who will be covered by ETIAS.

Comment: What I don't quite understand is what has got more difficult.  The UK was never part of Schengen and there was always passport control for the Eurostar.  Why is it taking so much longer now?

Comment: @neil The checks are more thorough now.  Many years ago, my passport would get a cursory check on the train.  Today, it is more like an airport.

Comment: @neil yeah, as badjohn said, the checks for non-EU countries are much more thorough. For an EU country they only need to check you have an EU passport - which the vast majority of passengers on Eurostar do. I remember multiple times just being waved through once they'd seen my face clearly matches the face on the passport. For a third country they need to check your passport more thoroughly, often including previous stamps, and then make another entry/exit stamp. This just takes much longer.

Comment: @Muzer Schengen border officials are really lax with Brits from what I've observed, not least in France; quick scan followed by a stamp. 10-15 seconds.

Comment: @Crazydre 10-15 seconds is about 3 or 4 times as long as it used to take from experience... and I reckon from my own experience it takes more like 30 seconds per person for the full check-and-stamp. Pre-Brexit I remember just showing my photo page and immediately being waved through.

Comment: @Muzer Also many countries have self-service for Brits, in which case (at least in IT & NL) you just hand over an empty page to the officer, they stamp it and off you go (though in certain countries if you show a residence permit card they won't stamp)